# localStorage cannot transfer data, does not work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, local-storage

I'm using html5's localStorage API.

The scenario is that the user clicks a button "Add to my list" so she can save to a list a name of a location.

The following code works perfect only in Chrome. Works for one window and also if two or more windows are open from the same source that is.
Works fine if only one window is open in Firefox and IE. If there are more than one windows, in IE do not get the data. In Firefox, if I click to add a name, adds it about 30 times.

I tried to implement my code based on examples I found.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="button"  value="Add to my list" onClick="savepoi(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML);"/>                                     

<script>

//listen if a storage happened to another window and call the right function
if (window.attachEvent) { // IE8 support
   window.attachEvent('onstorage', storageEvent);} 
else 
{window.addEventListener('storage', storageEvent, true);}

function storageEvent(event) {
//if something is added
   if(event.oldValue==null)
   {savepoib(event.newValue);}
}


function savepoi(a){
  //if no localStorage, set firs key=1, else add 1 to the existing
  //save key and name together
  if(localStorage.length==0)
  {localStorage.setItem(1,1+"-"+a);}
  else
  {localStorage.setItem((localStorage.length+1),(localStorage.length+1)+"-"+a);}

}

function savepoib(a){
  //split to get key and name 
  var b =a.split("-");
  var idi=b[0];//key
  var myname = b[1];//name

  if(localStorage.length==0)
  {localStorage.setItem(1,1+"-"+myname);}
  else
  {localStorage.setItem(idi,idi+"-"+myname);}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Storage events are a mess. I've done some work with it and things are not consistent. Chrome only fires events in other windows, Firefox fires in all windows, including the one where the changed happen, and IE, i don't remember what the trouble was.  Anyway, here's the code i used to smooth out the differences (it's a plugin for my store2.js library):

https://github.com/nbubna/store/blob/master/src/store.bind.js

Hope that helps.

FYI, for consistent behavior, i've considered trying to fake storage events using postMessage or something like that, but i've never had time to chase down the idea and see if it's really feasible.

Comment: Oh yeah, i remember, most IE implementations that i tried fired storage events, but the events were devoid of information, no newValue or oldValue or anything.  But this was pre-IE10 that i was doing this testing. Things may have changed.